# Working with multiple solutions with projects references on TFS

Tags: tfs, visual-studio-2013, version-control, branch, devops

We have recently moved to project references on all of our solutions that are managed on a TFS server, and we are using Visual Studio 2013. Our Dev Solution Tree looks something like this -

```
- Main Solution A(Solution)
   Core1 Client Library(Project reference)
   Core2 Client Library(Project reference)
   Core3 Client Library(Project reference)
   .... 
- Main Solution B(Solution)
   Core2 Client Library(Project reference)
   Core3 Client Library(Project reference)
   Core4 Client Library(Project reference)
   .... 
- Core1 Project (Solution)
   Client Library (Project that references all other projects in this solution)
   Project1 (Project)
   Project2 (Project)
   Project3 (Project)
- Core2 Project (Solution)
   Client Library (Project that references all other projects in this solution)
   Project1 (Project)
   Project2 (Project)
   Project3 (Project)
 ...
```

Everytime we want to start working on a big update to some core functionality we have 2 options: Either work on the dev branch of each solution and risk breaking it, or branch every solution that is going to be changed and *change all the refrences in each branched solution to work with the other branched projects*.

For example adding functionality to main solution B requires branching Main Solution B, Branching Core2 + Core3 + Core4 and changing all the project references in those new branches to the other new branches.

This is very time consuming to do for each work item and we feel like there is a smarter way of doing things but cannot figure one out. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

If they're tightly coupled to the extent you're describing, they should be branched and merged as a single unit.

Another option, albeit representing a bigger change to your workflow and development practices:

Break out anything shared between applications into NuGet packages and manage your shared references as NuGet packages instead of project references.

Comment: I talked with some team members (Im not very familiar with how NuGet works) and we agreed that switching to NuGet Packages might help a bit but still wont solve the underlying issue of switching references between branches as we will still have tight coupling between them. If we wont get any more advice on how to approach this we might consider to reduce the coupling between the solutions and/or move to NuGet Packages.

Comment: @T.Bogdan If you use NuGet packages, you **don't** use project references -- you use package references.